# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.KeyStroke when creating a JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, java-5, jsplitpane

I'm getting a random unreproducible Error when initializing a `JSplitPane` in with JDK 1.5.0_08. Note that this does not occur every time, but about 80% of the time:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.KeyStroke
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1093)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:465)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:210)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installDefaults(BasicSplitPaneUI.java:364)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installUI(BasicSplitPaneUI.java:300)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:652)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.setUI(JSplitPane.java:350)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.updateUI(JSplitPane.java:378)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(JSplitPane.java:332)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(JSplitPane.java:287)
    ...
```

Thoughts? I've tried cleaning and rebuilding my project so as to minimize the probability of corrupted class files.

Looking at [JDK-6434148 : ClassCastException thrown while running SwingSet2 demo](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434148), this seems to be a JDK bug. Any known workarounds? None are listed on the bug entry page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some searching in the [Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/), this looks like this might be a JDK bug that was only fixed in JDK 6.

See [JDK-6434148 : ClassCastException thrown while running SwingSet2 demo](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434148).

Answer (score 1):

Same exception had got thrown when i had upgraded java verion and db visualizer dint support jre7. and since 
Support for Java 7 was introduced in DbVisualizer 8.0 for Windows and Linux/UNIX.

Support for Java 7 on Mac OS X was introduced in DbVisualizer 9.1.

So Solution that worked for me : 
**Windows/Unix/Linux:**
    In the DbVisualizer installation directory there is an .install4j directory,
    In this directory create a file named pref_jre.cfg if it doesn't already exist,
    Open the file in a text editor,
    Add the complete path to the root directory for the Java installation you want to use. 
    Example: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.KeyStroke cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable....
```

If you are getting above error after installing java 7 in dbviz
then add Environment variabbles like: 
'DBVIS_JAVA_HOME' as a 'Variable Name' and java path like 
for ex. "C:\SWDTOOLS\IBM\RAD85\runtimes\base_v7\java"